# Can a statistical model have two unknown parameters?

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling

Is an $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution a statistical model if both the parameters are unknown? The definition I have in front of me only refers to one unknown parameter.

Comment: Yes, it can have two unknown parameters where the parameter space will now be two dimensional instead of one dimensional.

Comment: yes for the first question, and for the second question $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is a statistical model for all the cases when  $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are both known, both unknown and either one is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Some distributions such as Poisson and exponential have only one parameter. Other distributions such as binomial and normal have two.
(In the case of the binomial, the number of trials $n$ is often
known, and the success probability $p$ is often unknown.) There are
also distribution families with more than two parameters.

When you are doing inferential procedures (e.g., confidence intervals and tests of hypotheses) for data from a distribution with more than
one parameter, it is important to understand from the start which parameters are unknown (and subject to inference) and which are 
known.

For example, suppose you have data $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ from a normal population. If the mean $\mu$ is unknown and the 
standard deviation $\sigma = 3$ is known, then a 95% confidence
interval for $\mu$ is $\bar X \pm 1.96 \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ Thus
if $n = 4$ and the sample mean is $\bar X = 3.25$ then the CI
is $3.25 \pm 1.96(3/2)$ or $(0.31, 6.19)$.

By contrast, if $\sigma$ is unknown, and estimated by the
sample standard deviation $S = 3.19$, then a 95% CI for $\mu$ is
$\bar X \pm t^*S/\sqrt{4},$ where $t^* =  3.182$ is found from a table
of Student's t distribution (with degrees of freedom $df = n - 1 = 3.$ Then the CI is computed as $3.25 \pm 3.182(3.19/2)$ or 
$(-1.825, 8.325).$ So knowing whether $\sigma$ is known or
to be estimated by $S$ can make a noticeable difference in the CI.